# Selecting and grouping similar fields in mysql to populate a dropdown

Tags: mysql

I have a select field I need to populate from mysql in preparation to execute a search [when the form is submitted]

The data in the table looks something like [stainless steel finish types]

```
#3
#3 SP
#4
#4 LAS
#4 PP
#4 PI
#4 PVC
2B
2B PVC
2B/PI
```

I need to select and group them in the select control so that the options appear as:

```
<option value="#3">#3</option>
<option value="#4">#4</option>
<option value="2B">2B</option>
<option value="ALUM">ALUM</option>
<option value="QQ">QQ</option>
<option value="QQ 2A">QQ 2A</option>
<option value="RO PVC">RO PVC</option>
<option value="SCRP">SCRP</option>
<option value="SCRAP">SCRAP</option>
```

Without all the suffixes, now, not all the groups will be the first two characters and not all items are going to be grouped i.e. there are items in there like:

```
ALUM
QQ
QQ 2A
RO PVC
SCRP
SCRAP
```

Those items should not be grouped.

currently all I am doing is a straight select:

```
select distinct(finish) from inventory_data where `finish` != '' order by `finish`;
```

Unfortunately, it's an existing database that I can not change and there is no grouping table or relation to join on to do this for me.

Any suggestions on the best way to get this done?

**UPDATES**

- There are a little over 10,000 records, with around 50+ or so finish types
- There are some patterns, though I may be told to group things like "everything that starts with AB as AB but not ABS" to further complicate things, the AB may be contained in another finish type i.e. #2 ABS, so I can't use things like: LIKE '%AB%'

Comment: A few clarifying questions. 1) ALUM, QQ, etc would not be shown in the select, correct? 2) How many entries are there? (Ie, you may want to post-process in whatever language you are using.). 3) Are they are any patterns to the groups?

Comment: @Gohn67 I updated the question in response to your answers. ALUM & QQ do need to be shown, 10,000+ entries and yes, there are patterns, but those patterns can turn up in finishes that are not supposed to be in the group.  The result is that I have to distinctly select some finishes and then group others!

Comment: How often does this table change? If it's not often, maybe consider caching a pre-calculated version. Or add hook that will calculate a new version if a new entry is added. In addition, you may want to benchmark the performance of doing it programmatically. You may also stumble upon a good way to query the data that way too.

Comment: They buy sell and trade this inventory worldwide all day long .. it changes constantly :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we over think things.

The solution was to:

```
select distinct(finish) from inventory_data 
where `finish` != '' 
and 'finish' NOT REGEXP '^#2|^#4|^BA|etc' 
order by `finish`;
```

Then just add the finishes I need after the query. I can use different REGEXs for some of the more complicated conditions.